# JQM: Redirect after Ajax form post

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a function for an ajax post call that goes like this:

```
function submitForm() 
    {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'form.php',
                data:$('#form').serialize(),
                success:function(response)
                {
             /////////////
                    $.mobile.changePage('#page1', {
                            reloadPage: true
                        }, {
                            allowSamePageTranstion: true
                        }, {
                            transition: 'none'
                        });
                    return false;
             /////////////
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The code between the ///////////////'s is the one I am trying to use to navigate back to the main menu after a successful ajax form submit.  I do know that it works as I've tried with an alert and I see that the data is stored in MySQL. But I cannot figure out how to redirect back to my main page. I also have href="#page1" in the submit button, but all I get is a blank page that says "undefined".

Comment: why can't you use `location.href` inside the success handler

Comment: I never said I couldn't :P Gonna try it now :P

Comment: i should have made it an answer :p

Comment: Worked perfectly. MAke it an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: its ok accept @ Ankit Gautam answer glad that it solved ur problem...

Comment: Actually the href="#page1" worked I just forgot to remove the action from the <form>. But the (window.)location.href works as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on success function

write

```
window.location.href="redirect url"
```